# Command \upshape invalid in math mode

Tags: amsmath, flalign

The *problem* I meanwhile solved myself, but the *question* remains. I forgot a \text{} wrapper in a \flalign* env and got the mentioned error. Now, the math part isn't wrapped in \text{} (duh) which obviously begs the question: How can LaTeX know what's math and what's text? It can't be plaintext or position or columns that caused the error, as the following is harmless:

```
\begin{flalign*}
\omega=omega && \phi=phi && comment
\end{flalign*}
```

And neither my \ref{} links do any trouble in a MWE. And except those, anything was just plaintext. Any idea what was causing the trouble? (note: Everything is also inside an amsmath corollary/proof env.)

Comment: There are Plain TeX commands to enter and leave math mode.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Everything inside a math environment is treated as math, and outside, not as math. Are  you asking about what the underlying code is of those environments?  Maybe expanding your code fragment into an actual MWE would make the question clearer? Notice that the "text" portion of your fragment is set in `\mathit` so it's not text mode.

Comment: Easier said than done, given that my preamble is riddled with customized doodads :-) At the moment, I only could reproduce the error as a GNWE (giant non-working example), and of course I won't post my whole thesis here :-) So please be patient while I'm still trying...